# Xamarin - Recycled View gives errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-recyclerview

I'm new to app development and I'm trying to create a Recycled View on a Fragment, however there are some problems, it throws the following errors:

[image]

Code:

```
namespace Homecheck.Fragments {
    public class SmokeSensor : Fragment {
        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
        private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
        private List<ItemData> itemData;

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            recyclerView.HasFixedSize = true;

            layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(layoutManager);

            itemData = new List<ItemData>();
            itemData.Add(new ItemData() {title = "Testing", image = Resource.Drawable.ic_circle_red});

            adapter = new MyAdapter(itemData);
            recyclerView.SetAdapter(adapter);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SmokeSensor, container, false);
            recyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.smoke_recycler_view);

            return view;
        }
    }

    public class MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter {
        private List<ItemData> itemData;
        private TextView titleText;
        private ImageView imageId;

        public MyAdapter(List<ItemData> itemData) {
            this.itemData = itemData;
        }

        public class ViewHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public View mainView { get; set; }
            public TextView title { get; set; }
            public ImageView image { get; set; }

            public ViewHolder (View view) : base (view) {
                mainView = view;
            }
        }

        public override MyAdapter.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.SmokeItemView, null);

            titleText = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.item_title);
            imageId = itemLayoutView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.item_icon);

            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView) { title = titleText, image = imageId };

            return viewHolder;
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
            viewHolder.title.SetText(itemData[position]);
        }

        public override int getItemCount() {
            return itemData.Count();
        }
    }

    public class ItemData {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public int image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I know it's most likely a stupid mistake, but I can't seem to find it and fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type of `OnCreateViewHolder` is wrong, it should be `Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder`

You need to override `ItemCount`:

```
 public override int ItemCount {get{...}}
```

Wrong parameter type, fix it like this:

```
 public override void OnBindViewHolder(Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position)
```

Comment: It throws this: `'Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder' does not contain a definition for 'title' and no extension method 'title' accepting a first argument of type 'Android.Support.V7.Widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I suggest you try to understand what these error messages mean instead of just pasting them here